# Magento : 2 "Argument passed must be an instance of AuthorizerobinFactory"

Tags: magento2, error, di

I have two modules, as "AuthorizenetCim" and "AuthorizeRobin".

In "AuthorizenetCim" model file, I want to get collection of "AuthorizeRobin" module.

So my constructor for "AuthorizenetCim" (`/model/Gateway.php`) is:

```
public function __construct(
    \ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Helper\Data $helper,
    \ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Model\Gateway\Xml $xml,
    \ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Model\Gateway\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir $moduleDir,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    /*Injecting other module's model factory */
    \Neo\Authorizerobin\Model\AuthorizerobinFactory $authorizeRobinFactory,
    /*Injection done*/
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->moduleDir = $moduleDir;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->authorizeRobinFactory = $authorizeRobinFactory;

    parent::__construct(
        $helper,
        $xml,
        $responseFactory,
        $httpClientFactory,
        $data
    );
}
```

But I am getting following error for my constructor:

```
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 7 passed to ParadoxLabs\Authnetcim\Model\Gateway::__construct
() must be an instance of Neo\Authorizerobin\Model\AuthorizerobinFactory, array given, called in /var
/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and
 defined in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/ParadoxLabs/Authnetcim/Model/Gateway.php:182

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): ParadoxLabs
\Authnetcim\Model\Gateway-&gt;__construct(Object(ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Helper\Data), Object(ParadoxLabs
\TokenBase\Model\Gateway\Xml), Object(ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Model\Gateway\ResponseFactory), Object(Magento
\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Module\Dir), Object(Magento\Framework\Registry
), Array)


#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework
\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory-&gt;createObject('ParadoxLabs\\Aut...', Array)


#2 /var/ in <b>/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/ParadoxLabs/Authnetcim/Model/Gateway.php</b> on line 
<b>182</b><br />
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/308753050106"
}]}}
```

Comment: Try to remove an old generated files using `rm -rf var/generation/*` from the magento root directory

Comment: Thanks @SiarheyUchukhlebau worked for me. +1 from me. Also I can accept it as answer, if you want to give as answer

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to remove an old generated files using `rm -rf var/generation/*` command (`rm -rf generated/*` for the Magento >=2.2) from the magento root directory, because magento pre-generates all class files with their constructors. Generated classes extends the original classes and used by magento to call a plugins.

Comment: what to try when that doesn't work? xD

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs In case when this does not work you should check all classes passed as an arguments to the `__construct` method, seems some of it is incorrect.

Comment: also remember to compile: php bin/magento setup:di:compile